# How to calculate a percentage as an exponential progression?

Tags: java, math

What I want to do is very simple, but I can't figure out the math and code for it.

I have a percentage that I display in the console as a new number with each progressive step. So I know the exact percentage 1-100 each step. Assuming a constant progression, what I want is to only show the numbers that are on an some exponential function:

Instead of showing:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7....100

I want show only:

> 1,2,4,8,15,25,40,65,90,(100)

Or something like that. The idea is to show initial activity, but slow down on the percentage spamming soon after.

How can I do this? The only thing I can think of is to define a fixed array of numbers that are allowed to be printed (perhaps that is the best solution? I feel there should be a more elegant math based solution, though). Hmm, or perhaps fill such an array using an exponential function / easing curve.

Adding some information on how the percentage is acquired:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < batchjob.size(); i++) {
   int percent = 100 * i / batchjob.size();
   log.debug("Progress: {}/{} = {}%", i, batchjob.size(), percent));
}
```

Now I tried the following:

```java
final Set<Integer> progressDisplay = newHashSet(1, 2, 4, 8, 15, 25, 40, 65, 90, 100);

for (int i = 0; i < batchjob.size(); i++) {
   int percent = 100 * i / batchjob.size();
   if (progressDisplay.contains(percent)) {
        log.debug("Progress: {}/{} = {}%", i, batchjob.size(), percent));
   }
}
```

However, this results in something like:

> 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,8,8,8,8,8,8,8...etc

---

## Solution

I went with a combination of the accepted answer and a fixed array. I finally decided on a simple array as I can tweak the numbers more easily.

```java
final int[] progressDisplay = {1, 3, 8, 20, 50, 75, 100};
int lastMatchingIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < batchjob.size(); i++) {
    processBatchJob(batchjob.get(i));
    int percent = 100 * i / batchjob.size();
    if (progressDisplay[lastMatchingIndex] == percent) {
        log.debug("Progress: {}/{} = {}%", i, batchjob.size(), percent);
        lastMatchingIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: When installers show steady, incremental progress up until it gets stuck at 60% for a while, and then suddenly jump to 90%, that's a bug and not something you should try to implement :P

Comment: I agree @thatotherguy, but this is on the terminal :) (but maybe the jumps don't need to be so big though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//initial exponential function check
int baseNum = 2;
final int exponent = 3;
int check = Math.pow(baseNum, exponent);
for(int x = 1; x <= 100; x++){
    if(x == check){
        System.out.println(x);
        baseNum++;
        check = Math.pow(baseNum, exponent);
    }
}
```

That is just an example; you didn't provide enough information for a complete solution. You should be able to apply the idea however: you can apply the exponential function once, and then as you iterate, check against the function's output, and - if it is the same - reapply the exponential function and repeat.

Comment: Actually this is pretty neat, as it also solves the issue of repeating numbers (111,222,444,888 etc). I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it simple you can always just use two counters and increase one based on the one that iterates per loop so the jump gets larger each time:

```
int j = 1, k = 1;
while (k < 100)
{
    System.out.println(k);
    j++;
    k = k + j;
}
```

If you want to reduce the jump frequency you can change `k = k + j` to `k = k + j / 2;` or something along those lines.  If you want to print less numbers faster, increase the rate `j` increases.  Adjust it specifically to what fits you the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can define an exponential function within the for loop's increment argument. The following is an example of x^2.

```
for(int x = 1; x <= 100; x*=2) {
    System.out.println(foo[x]); // 1/2/4/8/16/32/64
}
```